# Transforming keras model output during training and use multiple losses

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, autoencoder, seq2seq

```
       if self.use_embedding:
            input_x = Input(shape=(self.input_length,), name='embedding_input')
            x = Embedding(self.input_dim, self.embedding_dim)(input_x)
        else:
            input_x = Input(shape=(self.input_length,self.input_dim), name='notes_input')
            x = input_x

        encoder_input_list = [input_x]
        encoded = self._build_encoder(x)
        self.encoder = Model(inputs=encoder_input_list, outputs=encoded)

        
        encoded_input = Input(shape=(self.latent_rep_size,), name='encoded_input')
        
        if self.use_embedding:
            input_decoder_x = Input(shape=(self.output_dim,), name='embedding_input_decoder_start')
            #decoder_x = Embedding(self.output_dim, self.output_dim, input_length=1)(input_decoder_x)
            decoder_x = input_decoder_x
        else:
            input_decoder_x = Input(shape=(self.output_dim,), name='input_decoder_start')
            decoder_x = input_decoder_x

        autoencoder_decoder_input_list = [input_decoder_x, encoded]
        decoder_input_list = [input_decoder_x, encoded_input]
        autoencoder_input_list = [input_x, input_decoder_x]
        autoencoder_output_list = []

        
        if self.teacher_force:
            ground_truth_input = Input(shape=(self.output_length, self.output_dim), name='ground_truth_input')
            decoder_input_list.append(ground_truth_input)
            autoencoder_decoder_input_list.append(ground_truth_input)
            autoencoder_input_list.append(ground_truth_input)
        else:
            ground_truth_input = None

        if self.history:
            history_input = Input(shape=(self.latent_rep_size,), name='history_input')
            decoder_input_list.append(history_input)
            autoencoder_decoder_input_list.append(history_input)
            autoencoder_input_list.append(history_input)
        else:
            history_input = None

        decoded= self._build_decoder(decoder_x, encoded_input, ground_truth_input, history_input)
        
        loss_list = []
        loss_weights_list = []
        sample_weight_modes = []

        loss_weights_list.append(1.0)
        sample_weight_modes.append('temporal')
        loss_list.append(self.vae_loss)
        metrics_list = ['accuracy']
        
        decoder_output = decoded
        
        self.decoder = Model(inputs=decoder_input_list, outputs=decoder_output, name='decoder')

        decoder_final_output = self.decoder(autoencoder_decoder_input_list)

        if isinstance(decoder_final_output, list):
            autoencoder_output_list.extend(decoder_final_output)
        else:
            autoencoder_output_list.append(decoder_final_output)
            
        self.autoencoder = Model(inputs=autoencoder_input_list, outputs=autoencoder_output_list, name='autoencoder')
        self.autoencoder.compile(optimizer=self.optimizer,
                                 loss=loss_list,
                                 loss_weights=loss_weights_list,
                                 sample_weight_mode=sample_weight_modes,
                                 metrics=metrics_list)
```

```
Here is my code for a variational sequence to sequence model. I want to transform the decoder output during the training so that It gives me two other matrices and use two different loss functions for the new matrices. So the total loss should be like L_total = L_mat1 + L_mat2 + L_mat3 - KL loss. Is there a way to do it in Keras? I have the ground truth values for the transformed matrices. Any good soul would help me with this?
```

Answer (score 0):

I've added an example on how to implement a matrix split operation to this colab notebook:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/127DY9OUWasFQzM9G2AH4RQO8ryhSTJny?usp=sharing

The short answer is that you can use a lambda to split the output of any layer.

In my simple example:

```
  inputs = layers.Input(shape=(2,))
  d = layers.Dense(10)(inputs)
  out1, out2 = layers.Lambda(lambda x: (x[:, :5], x[:, 5:]))(d)
  model = keras.Model(inputs, [out1, out2])  
  model.compile(loss=['mse', 'mae'])
  return model
```

The lambda layer splits the first 5 columns of the matrix into out1 and the last 5 cols into out2.

Comment: I need to send the output to an external function like: `def transform(d): ... return matrix1, matrix 2`.

Comment: You can use Lambda(function_name) where function_name is your transform function.

Comment: something like mat1,mat2 = Lambda(transform)(d)?

Comment: assuming transform returns 2 matrices, yes. be aware that transform is going to be taking a tensor as input, not np arrays. after transform is working correctly try adding the annotation @tf.function to it.